# How do I run a standalone program in OpsWorks?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm sure there's a simple answer. Our program is an executable jar file, and we have a shell script wrapper for it.

- OpsWorks grabs the distribution zip file from S3
- We're trying to unzip that and run the script file located in `bin/run_server.sh`

I'm currently down the path of writing a custom deploy recipe for it, running on a layer of type "Other".

Here is my attempt :

```
include_recipe 'deploy'

node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|

    # assume the zip file has been extracted at this point, 
    # and the CWD is the extracted contents
    execute "run the server" do
        command 'bash bin/run_server.sh'
        action :run
    end
end
```

This fails claiming that it cannot find `bin/run_server.sh`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting cwd explicitly?

```
execute "run the server" do
    command 'bash bin/run_server.sh'
    cwd "/path/to/your/stuff"
end
```

Comment: I don't know where the zip file is downloaded. I've ssh-ed into the instance and couldn't find any trace of it, or its contents.

Comment: It should be in node[:deploy][application][:deploy_to], but maybe you're missing a deployment step since you're using a custom layer. Can you share more details about your custom recipe setup and app configuration?

Comment: I think what's happening is that setup includes the deployment step, but the app has yet to be deployed. I think to achieve the desired effect I need to add a deploy hook to my app itself, so that chef runs it as soon as it receives application code, not on setup.